# C++ and Cocoa: how to mix

Tags: c++, xcode, cocoa, visual-c++

I need to make a following pseudo code:

In .h file:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
    void MyFunc();
};
```

In .cpp/.m/.mm/. file:

```
Foo::Foo()
{
#if MAC
// Cocoa-specific initialization goes here
#endif
#if Windows
// Windows-specific initialization goes here
#endif
}
```

I am working with XCode and MSVC and developing using wxWidgets, so I need to be able to include the files in both MSVC and XCode projects.

What is the best possible solution? I'd like to have a one class - meaning 2 files (.h/.cpp).

Thank you.

[EDIT]
I found this: [How to create Cocoa objects in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788427/how-to-create-cocoa-objects-in-c?rq=1) and the comment from geovar shows that it is possible, but I can't find that option in the XCode I have (version 3.2 64 bit for Snow Leopard).
Any pointers?

Thank you.
[/EDIT]

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution?  What's not working?

Comment: @Adam, first, which files needs to be made? Second, can I put Cocoa-specific code in .cop file? I don't know the answer, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor test `__OBJC__` can be used to conditionally declare Objective-C code in a header that might also be used in "pure" C++ files.  For example:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
  @interface Whatever : NSObject
  {
    . . .
  }
  . . .
  @end

#else

  class Whatever;

#endif

class SomeCPPClass
{
  . . .
};

// this actually works; the pointer form of the class
// can be passed freely from Objective-C++ to C++ through
// a plain-C or C++ routine such as this one
void SomeFunction (Whatever* param);
```

For source files that need Objective-C++, rename them (to `WhateverName.mm`).  Maybe this is required, maybe not, but it's at least convenient because you don't have to set up custom build rules.

Note that even though the files are renamed and using the Objective-C++ compiler, they can still be 99% C++ if you want them to be (with obvious exceptions; e.g. nothing can be named `id`).  In general, anything you want to do from C++ will work fine.

Having said that, read up on Objective-C's interactions with C++ because there are some quirks.  For example, Objective-C exceptions *do not call C++ object destructors when they're thrown* (at least, in some versions of the language).  Note that C++ exceptions *do* behave as expected in Objective-C++; I'm referring to the Objective-C exceptions that you have to catch with `@try`.  Given an RAII-style class in C++, the only cleanup solution I could think of was to add a method that performs conditional cleanup and call it explicitly, like this:

```
@try
{
    SomeRAIIStyleObject x;
    doSomethingThatMightTriggerObjCException(x);
}
. . .
@finally
{
    x.tearDownIfNeeded();
}
```

Comment: Will I be able to include the .mm file in the MSVC project? How do I do that?

Comment: I don't know much about MSVC; I imagine there is a way to set up a rule that treats `.mm` as a C++ file (as long as you use `#ifdef __OBJC__` in the file at the right points, that's probably enough).  Alternately, put the `.mm` only in the Mac version of the project and wrap it in pure C or C++ functions (that accept nothing more than pointers to Objective-C classes); then in your class `Foo` above, make the Mac initialization call the pure C or C++ function wrappers only and keep the file that defines `Foo` as regular C++.